# Plotting in python using group by and sum

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a graph using the below data. I need to have graph Year vs Txns

Original Data which is dataset1= in the code

```
WeekDay Day Month   Year    Time    Txns
   1     5    1     2015      3       1
   1     5    1     2015      4       4
   1     5    1     2015      5       1
   1     5    1     2015      7       2
```

This is the data after group by and sum which is plot= in the code

```
Index       Txns
(2014, 12)  5786
(2015, 1)   70828
(2015, 2)   63228
(2015, 3)   74320
```

my code:

```
plot = dataset1.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['Txns'].sum()
plot_df = plot.unstack('Month').loc[:, 'Txns']
plot_df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(plot_df.index.tolist(), freq='2015')
plot_df.plot()
```

I get this error everytime:

> KeyError: 'the label [Txns] is not in the [columns]'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just `data.groupby('Year').Txns.sum()` if you want to group by year and sum `Txns`?

and `.plot()` if you wanted to plot it:

[image]

or yearly lines:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am actually looking to plot a 3 different line charts for each year showing me the txns in y axis and months in x axis

Comment: You could build a `pivot_table` and plot it. `pvt = pd.pivot_table(data, columns='Year', index=['Month'], aggfunc='sum', values='Txns')` and then `pvt.plot()` but beware of NaN values in columns